# data annotation where two properties are unique in mvc 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, data-annotations

I have following Category table as below and I have use Entity framework model first:

```
ID => int , primary key , unique
CategoryName => varchar(50)
ParentCategoryID => int
```

I have applied unique constraint for two column categoryName and ParentCategoryID by executing following query:

```
ALTER TABLE Category
ADD CONSTRAINT UQ_YourTable_ConstraintName UNIQUE(CategoryName, ParentCategoryID)
```

Here, what I want is that to validate the input if the commbine form of categoryName and ParentCategoryID is unique using dataannotation. So, I have created the partial class for category as:

```
 [MetadataType(typeof(TestEntityValidation))]
    public partial class Category{
    }

    public class TestEntityValidation{
       //............ data annotation
        public string CategoryName{ get; set; }

       //............ data annotation
        public string ParentCategoryID { get; set; }
    }
```

what could be code for data annotation so that Combination of CategoryName and ParentCategoryID is always unique and show error if duplicate data is entered by user.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you can do this using Data Annotation, but here is what you could do

```
public ActionResult Validate(SomeModel model)
{
 // check for this condition with db using the 'model'

 if(combination_is_NOT_unique)
 {
  ViewBag.Message = "Not Unique";
  return View("NameOfTheView");
 }

 // else
 do the normal stuff

}
```